# How to add a curly animated effect to texts using CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

Well I wish to show a curly shaking animated effect to texts using CSS and this is how it looks like (ignore the background). I think it's a cool effect but have no idea how to do it.

[image]

An example will be very helpful in CSS animation or a script is also acceptable. Thanks in advance for the help !:)

Comment: You can do this kind of effect with normal jQuery, however you may prefer to look at this: http://jackrugile.com/jrumble/ - put a custom font inside a div and shake it, shake it, shake it like a polaroid picture.

Comment: @redditor hmm I can relate to demo 16 but isn't it running too vigorously ! :D I think this will do to some extent. Thanks ! :)

Comment: It's funny, because I was looking at Demo 16 too. Check out this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/CwgCL/ - there will be away to slow it down.

Comment: Look at this mate

http://elrumordelaluz.github.io/csshake/

Comment: this might help aswell, with css3 http://www.cssreset.com/css3-webkit-animation-shake-links/

Comment: Here it is with the speed variable - http://jsfiddle.net/CwgCL/1/

Comment: @redditor can we control the shake factor ?

Comment: ^_^ you are welcome, I like this shake, you can do more of thing without tired ..^^

Comment: @redditor haa got it ! :D

Comment: @caramba thanks I will use it as well ! :D

Comment: @Geniusknight *Another* thing that might point you in the right direction: http://voidcanvas.com/give-awesome-wave-effect-to-your-texts-with-jquery-animation-and-tweenmax/

Comment: @redditor haha I was browsing the same page as well ! lol !

Answer (score 0):

## Is it possible?

**No**, the effect you're looking for is **not** possible, because the different frames in the images can not be derived from each other. With a lot of hard work you could make something similar if you would have the initial image as a SVG, but still it would be quite a way off.

## So how close can we get?

So, in the comment section a lot of the comments are proposing to shake the image. Although this will get an interesting result, the original actually is not shaken at all. It will however probably be necessary to shake it a tiny bit to get some of the feeling, although it is a poor substitute. Next one could play around with the new CSS3 `filter` property to get some interesting results. For example increasing `contrast()` on some frames, or building/finding a far better SVG filter which you could add using the `url()` property. For the CSS3 filters I would recommend [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) and for the SVG filters there is nothing better than [the original spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html) I fear (although there are some ready filters here and there on the internet as well).

Just another thought I had: a `blur` `blur` `sharpen` sequence could do wonders as well for just the line layer. Keeping the original background layer intact such as in the original gif.

## The animation part

And just to be thorough, you would use the above properties next in a discontinuous way in a CSS3 'animation' switching from one state to the next like such (repeating each state twice to get the right effect).

```
 @keyframes animationName {
  0%{ transform: rotate(r) translate(x,y); filter: somefilter(f) }
  19%{ /* same as above */ }
  20%{ /* slightly different values for some or all of `r`, `x`, `y` and `f` */ }
  39%{ /* same as above again */ }
  /*etc.*/
 }
```

Comment: What about different custom fonts?

Comment: @jantimon: Custom fonts is just part of doing everything by hand, that's the same as saying: custom fonts, custom graphics and custom animation timing.

Comment: Just take a look at the desired output there are different fonts! ;)
Using multiple fonts is better than saying "not possible" depending on how important this feature is

Comment: @jantimon: Just look at the desired output, everything is different there! ;-) Redrawing a font two or three times to get the desired look will indeed work, but that's hardly a CSS affair then anymore.

Comment: The question is only about the text